# Instagram API Undefined Images Urls (Node.Js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, instagram

I can not get Instagram API's Pictures's links.
When I log on it, I get 'undefined'

I use Node.JS and this API:
https://github.com/huttarichard/instagram-private-api

```
var Client = require('instagram-private-api').V1;
var device = new Client.Device('xxx');
var storage = new Client.CookieFileStorage(__dirname + '/cookies/someuser.json');
var _ = require('lodash');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

Client.Session.create(device, storage, 'xxxxxusername***', '*****passwordxxxx')
    .then(function(session) {
    var accountId = '976677053'
    var feed = new Client.Feed.UserMedia(session, accountId);
    Promise.mapSeries(_.range(0, 20), function() {
      return feed.get();
    })
    .then(function(results) { var media = _.flatten(results); console.log(media) })
    });
```

Comment: Mehh, Instagram private APIs are a nightmare lately

Comment: I don't know much about it but in the quick follow example there they use 'someuser' in the device declaration also, where you have 'xxx'. Sorry if that doesn't help.

Comment: don't worry. Normally I put unique name in the field.  I change it before publish here.
And I can get datas when I write `console.log(media)` but they are not pictures' urls, other informations